# No data returning from ajax $.post()

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, post

I am having trouble getting any response text from my jQuery AJAX post:

```
$('document').ready(function()
{

    $('#saveRouteTrace').click(function(){

        // Build latStr and lonStr
        if(saveChanges()) {
            $.post('changeRouteTrace.php', {    
                    id: traceRouteId 
                   },
            function(data) {
                if(data.success) {
                    alert(data.reason);
                }
                else {
                    alert("Error: " + data.reason); 
                }                   
            }, 'json');
        }
    });
});
```

I am returning a response like:

```
{ "success": true, "reason": "because it worked" }
```

from the server, but the function(data) code never executes.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hard to tell, the code looks good. Are you sure the request is sent? Does `saveChanges()` return `true`? How do you create the response? What can you see in the network tab of your favorite debugging tool? You need to add a lot more information.

Comment: Can you check to see if the script I'd actually posting data to the server?

Comment: You **are** returning `{ "success": true, "reason": "because it worked" }` or you think/would like to be returning this JSON (there is a difference between the two)? [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) knows the answer. Ask him.

Comment: add the .ajaxError under your doc ready.

$('body').ajaxError(function() {
  $(this).append('Triggered ajaxError handler.');
});

Comment: I'm sure the request is sent, because changes are occurring on the server-side.  I am echoing { "success": true, "reason": "bc it worked" }, is this all I need to do?

Comment: I'm lookin in the chrome debugger at the requests being  sent.  Thanks, all

Comment: if you get rid of your `if...else` in your success function and just have an `alert('here')`, do you get that?  Also, change your datatype from `json` to `text` and just `alert(data)` to see what you get.

Comment: Also, did you get any error when you add an `$.ajaxError` handler like @Peter suggested?

Comment: @user507016 , Check the answer below, I think your problem is returning a json from the server side instead of echoing.

Answer (score 0):

You can check using FireBug if the request is sent and if the response looks ok. If the request is sent, but you don't get a proper response, it may be easier to create a test form in HTML and post the data using that form. Debugging that is easier than using the javascript response, because you can just keep refreshing after a change and check the response in the browser.

Comment: I checked the Chrome Debugger and I'm getting the expected response from changeRouteTrace.php, but sitll nothing from my function(data){} function.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your savechanges() function returns a value, this code snapshot works fine in my system.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#saveRouteTrace').click(function(){

        // Build latStr and lonStr
        if(saveChanges()) {
            $.post('stackoverflowajax.php', {    
                    id: 9,
                    name:'Tsegay' 
                   },
            function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                if(data.success) {
                    alert(data.reason);
                }
                else {
                    alert("Error: " + data.reason); 
                }                  
            }, 'json');
        }
    });
        function saveChanges(){
            //This is a debuging code ... Make sure it return a value
                return true;
            }
    });
```

This is the file on the server side. I am echoing the json file.

```
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
            //This do not work
            return '{ "success": true, "reason": "because it worked" }';
        //this works fine
        echo '{ "success": true, "reason": "because it worked" }';
    }
```